# C++ - Alternative to base-class function-pointer calls

Tags: c++, inheritance, function-pointers, associative-array, pointer-to-member

I have found many posts where it was pretty clearly stated that a derived class function **CANNOT** be assigned to a base-class function-pointer. So I wish to know, how to approach and solve the following situation:

Suppose I have the following base `class`

```
class base {
protected:
    typedef void (base::*base_fp)();
    typedef std::map<std::string, base_fp> array;

    array associativeArray;    
};
```

The main purpose of this class is to have a "`associative-array` of `functions`" property.

So what I wanted was for every derived child to be able to add their methods to the "associativeArray"

```
this->associativeArray["Method"] = &child::method; // from the child class
```

My original intention for using this was to call different methods depending on requirement without using conditional statements. It would have been in a try-catch block to handle the case for a non-existent index. Since my original approach is not possible, so what will be the right way of doing this?

**EDIT:** A use-case example

Suppose the associative array is an array of "algorithm" `functions`.
Then for user "algorithm" input, I should be able to call the corresponding method defined in the child class

```
(this->*associativeArray.at("algorithm"))();
```

Comment: When calling one of these, how would you know which derived type to cast the function pointer to, should you be able to mix both base and derived member function pointers in the same map? I mean you have to know the exact type of the object the member function belongs to when you call it don't you?

Comment: But *when you call* these functions, don't you need to know the exact type the function pointer belongs to? You have to have a pointer to an object of that type to call them with as well.

Comment: Suppose you've managed to populate `associativeArray` the way you want. How do you plan to use it? Show an example of the expected usage.

Comment: Member function pointers need to be called *on a specific object* of the correct type that the functions belong to.

Comment: What C++ standards are available?  This is much simpler with C++11 and later.

Comment: @StephenNewell Any standard that gets the job done.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have added a use case the question

Comment: @Galik "You have to have a pointer to an object of that type to call them with as well" ? Wouldn't it be possible to just use an instance of the child?

Comment: @Daolagajao Yes, as long as you match the correct type of the child with the function pointer it came from.

Comment: I wonder if member functions are not really what you need here but just general purpose functions not bound to specific objects?

Comment: What's `this` in your example? An object of what type does it point to?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Base or child as all of them have access to the associative array

Comment: Base is of one type and child is a different type. You can't call a member function from a base object using a child pointer and vice versa

Comment: @Galik You can, of course, call base class' methods on derived class' instance; just not the other way round.

Comment: I think you have some fundamental misunderstanding of how class inheritance and class method pointers work. Using `base_fp` you can only call a method in the base class. It cannot call a method in any derived class. That's it. Nothing else. Associative arrays are not a factor in any of this.

Comment: Oh that. Ok. But in this case, won't the base class only call its own member function if it has an index associated with it; otherwise it would through an exception

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That I did read about. I stated that what I want was another approach to how to achieve this.

Comment: I suppose the answer to this is that you can't do what you want. If you were to explain the problem you are trying to solve, then maybe someone could suggest a solution?

Comment: You might be looking for CRTP; something like `template <typename T> class base { typedef void (T::*fp)(); void call(const std::string& method) { static_cast<T*>(this)->*associativeArray[method])(); }}; class child : public base<child> {};`

Comment: @Galik I suppose so. Thought I would be quite easy to store member functions in an array and call them without using conditions

Comment: @Daolagajao It is, just not member functions.

Comment: @Galik Yeah, that was what I meant. I am checking the answer now to see the proposed approach

Comment: Maybe you could have a separate "algorithm" class that subclasses of base can supply their own derived type of? So `Base` has a `map<string, algorithm*> algos;` and derived classes can supply their own classes derived from `algorithm`?

Comment: For a pointer-to-member to work, you need to make sure, *statically*, that the object in question actually has the pointed-to member. The `->*` operator doesn't do any run time type checking.

Answer (score 4):

The closest I can get to what you want is using `std::function` (available since C++11).  First, we'll change your `typedef`s, both for modernization purposes and to use `std::function`:

```
class base {
protected:
    using base_fp = std::function<void ()>;
    using fn_array = std::map<std::string, base_fp>;
    fn_array fns;

public:
    void call_fn(std::string const &fn_name) {
        auto it = fns.find(fn_name);
        if(it != fns.end()) {
            it->second();
        }
        else {
            // error case
        }
    }
};
```

Because `fn_array` stores `std::function`s, it'll work with anything we can treat as a callable.  This can't work directly with member functions (`std::invoke` may do the trick, but I haven't used that library feature), but you can use trivial closures to get similar behavior.

```
class derived : public base {
public:
    derived() {
        fns["foo"] = [this]() { foo(); };
    }

private:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    }
};
```

You can leverage this using code like the following:

```
int main() {
    derived d;
    d.call_fn("foo");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want type-safety, you'd need to use a different type in your `map` value` (e.g., `std::map<std::string, std::function<void (int, char, SomeCustomType)>>`).  If you need to support multiple signatures in your `map`, you'd have to use some sort of type-safe wrapper (e.g., `std::variant` if you're in C++17).  This is the same issue if you're using raw function pointers as in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what do you need is `static_cast` because it is safe to use between two functions bearing same signatures, even being engendered from the same class hierarchy.

```
class base {

   protected:
     typedef void (base::*fn)() ;
     base(){
     fn_arr["foo"]=&base::foo;  
     }  
     void foo()  {
        cout << "i'm foo" << endl;
     }

   public:
     map<std::string, fn> fn_arr;
};

class derived : public base {

   protected:
      void bar() {
          cout <<"i'm bar" << endl;
      }

   public:
      derived() {
          fn_arr["bar"]=static_cast<fn>(&derived::bar);  
      }
};
```

[see this demo](https://ideone.com/7IN9Um)